# SwiftUI Infinite Carousel with TabView and AsyncImage - How to Achieve Carousel Infinite Loop?

Tags: swiftui

I've been trying to create an infinite carousel in SwiftUI using a TabView with images fetched from a service. Once the service responds, the offers are passed to the Carousel view, where they are displayed using AsyncImage. However, I haven't been able to achieve an infinite carousel behavior.

Here's the code for the Carousel view:

```
struct Carousel: View {
    
    // [Properties and initializers]
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $currentTabIndex) {
            ForEach(images) { image in
                // [AsyncImage and other content]
            }
        }
        .frame(width: screenWidth, height: 200)
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
        .indexViewStyle(.page)
        .onChange(of: currentTabIndex) { newValue in
            // [Logic for changing currentTabIndex]
        }
        .accessibilityIdentifier("CarouselView")
    }
    
    // [Other functions]
}

struct Carousel_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    // [Preview code]
}
```

I would like to make this Carousel infinite so that when the user swipes left at index 0, it shows the last image, and when swiping right at the last index, it shows the first image. I've tried adding the first and last images to the images array, but it's not working as expected.

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to achieve an infinite loop behavior for this Carousel in SwiftUI. All suggestions and code examples are welcome. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I know it's late but you could also have a look at this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77771658/paginated-infinite-scrolling-for-a-scrollview-containing-a-vstack-on-mac-cat/77779290#77779290

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this approach, where you add 2 extra (unseen) tabs and a `.onChange(...)` to
control the carousel functionality.

```
struct Carousel: View {
    @State var currentTabIndex = 0
    // for testing
    @State var images = ["image-0", "image-1", "image-2", "image-3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $currentTabIndex) {
            Spacer().tag(-1) // <-- here
            ForEach(images.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                VStack {
                    Text("image \(index)")
                    // other views ...
                }.tag(index)  // <-- here
            }
            Spacer().tag(images.count) // <-- here
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
        .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .never))
        // -- here
        .onChange(of: currentTabIndex) {
            // more logic here if need be
            if currentTabIndex == images.count {
                currentTabIndex = 0
            } else if currentTabIndex == -1 {
                currentTabIndex = images.count-1
            }
        }
        .accessibilityIdentifier("CarouselView")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Carousel()
    }
}
```

Comment: If user lets say scrolls 100 images there would be lot of memory usage won't t? Is there a way to limit to 3 Vstacsk in memory, and replaec them continuous?

Comment: I have not looked into memory management. You could try looking into `LazyVStack`, see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
.onChange(of: currentTabIndex) {
        withAnimation {
            currentTabIndex = (currentTabIndex + 1) % images.count
        }
    }
```