# Infinite/Wrap around ScrollView with paging in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I wrap the scrollview below such that when the user scrolls left-right on the first item past a certain threshold, the scrollview displays the last item and vice versa when the user swipes right-left on the last item?

```
struct WildlifeView: View {
    var imageNames: [String] {
        Array(0...4).map {"wildlife-\($0)"}
    }
    
    var titles: [String] {
        ["American Eagle", "Tiger", "Lion", "Ram", "Hummingbird"]
    }
    
    @State private var scrollTargetBehavior = CarouselScrollTargetBehavior()
    @State private var currentItemId: String?
    @State private var scrollXOffset: CGFloat = 0
    private var currentPage: Int {
        imageNames.firstIndex(where: { $0 == currentItemId}) ?? 0
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ZStack {
                GeometryReader(content: { screen in
                    
                    Image(imageNames[currentPage])
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: screen.size.width, height: 320)
                        .clipped()
                    
                    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                        HStack(spacing: 0) {
                            ForEach(imageNames, id: \.self) { imageName in
                                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                                        VStack() {
                                            Spacer()
                                            Text(titles[currentPage])
                                                .font(.largeTitle.bold())
                                                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                                .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                                                .frame(height: 80)
                                                .opacity(1.0 - (min(abs(geometry.frame(in: .global).origin.x)/100.0, 1.0)))
                                                .onChange(of: geometry.frame(in: .global)) { oldFrame, newFrame in
                                                    scrollXOffset = newFrame.origin.x
                                                }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                            }
                        }
                        .scrollTargetLayout()
                    }
                    .frame(height: 320)
                    .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
                    .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
                    .scrollPosition(id: $currentItemId)
                })
            }
            .frame(height: 320)
            .onChange(of: scrollXOffset, { oldValue, newValue in
                
                print("scrollXOffset: \(newValue)")
                let itemWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
                
                if currentPage == imageNames.count - 1, abs(newValue) >= (itemWidth * CGFloat(imageNames.count-1) + itemWidth/4)  {
                    // we're on the last page and user has scrolled a quarter of the width
                    withAnimation {
                        currentItemId = imageNames.first
                    }
                } else if currentPage == 0, newValue >= (itemWidth/4) {
                    // we're on the first page and user has scrolled a quarter of the width
                    withAnimation {
                        currentItemId = imageNames.last
                    }
                }
            })
            
            PageControl(numberOfPages: imageNames.count,
                        currentPage: currentPage,
                        currentPageIndicatorColor: .orange,
                        pageIndicatorColor: .white) { value in
                currentItemId = imageNames[value]
            }.frame(height: 30)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(.black)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Edit: Updated the code to use x offset when scrolling to try and achieve this but there are some issues:

1. The animation is wonky when scrolling before the first and after the last item. It doesn't animate the same way as a the regular scroll between items.
2. If the user continues to scroll and doesnt end the touch until way beyond the thresholds specified in `onChange`, the scroll happens to an additional index at the start/end of the scrollview.

See behavior below:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you could try this approach at:[carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76824297/swiftui-infinite-carousel-with-tabview-and-asyncimage-how-to-achieve-carousel/76824473#76824473). It uses `TabView`, but the principle is the same for `ScrollView`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine, thanks. I'll take a look at that. Meanwhile, I've updated my question to include code with checking the scrolling x offset but the animation effect is not quite the same as normal scrolling between the first and last items. Could you check?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I tried the tab view suggestion from the link but the app crashes if scrolled before the first and after the last element. It also displays two additional page dots. The code can be found [here](https://justpaste.it/a0m0x) . Could you take a look? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach, using a `TabView` with a second `@State var imgIndex`
for the array of pictures, and `.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))` to make sure the dots do not show.

```
struct WildlifeCarouselView: View {
    let imageNames = Array(0...4).map{"wildlife-\($0)"}
    let titles = ["American Eagle", "Tiger", "Lion", "Ram", "Hummingbird"]
    
    @State var currentTabIndex = 0
    @State var imgIndex = 0  // <-- here

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ZStack {
                GeometryReader(content: { screen in
                    Image(imageNames[imgIndex])  // <-- here
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: screen.size.width, height: 320)
                        .clipped()
                    
                    TabView(selection: $currentTabIndex) {
                        Spacer().tag(-1)
                        ForEach(titles.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                            GeometryReader { geometry in
                                VStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text(titles[index])
                                        .font(.largeTitle.bold())
                                        .foregroundStyle(.red)
                                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                                        .frame(height: 80)
                                        .opacity(1.0 - (min(abs(geometry.frame(in: .global).origin.x)/100.0, 1.0)))
                                }.tag(index)
                            }
                        }
                        Spacer().tag(titles.count)
                    }
                    .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never)) // <-- here
                    .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .never))
                    .onChange(of: currentTabIndex) {
                        if currentTabIndex == titles.count {
                            currentTabIndex = 0
                        } else if currentTabIndex == -1 {
                            currentTabIndex = titles.count - 1
                        }
                        imgIndex = currentTabIndex  // <-- here
                    }
                    .frame(height: 320)
                    .accessibilityIdentifier("CarouselView")
                })
            }
            .frame(height: 320)
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(.black)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Note, your opacity values `1.0 - (min(abs(geometry.frame(in: .global).origin.x)/100.0, 1.0))` are still completely wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. I know this is not specific to the question but could you point out how is the opacity wrong? I logged the values and the absolute value ranges from 0 to > 1 so I take the minimum of the that or 1.0 in order to affect opacity.

Comment: I added
 `let _ = print("---> index: \(index) opacity: \(1.0 - (min(abs(geometry.frame(in: .global).origin.x)/100.0, 1.0))) ")` just after `.opacity(...)`.
 I sometimes get a .55 or 0.77, often a 1.0 or 0.95 etc... for the currently displayed view,
 and 0 for the others that are not displayed.
 It seems to me that there is no need for `.opacity(...)` when using `TabView` if all
 you do/want is 1 and 0 opacity.
The code presented works very well for me, hope it works for you as well.

Comment: Note, if my answer helped, consider accepting it by ticking the tick mark next to it, it turns green.